# dask / pandas categorical transformation differences

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dask

I am managing larger than memory csv files of mostly categorical data. Initially I used to create a large csv file, then read it via Pandas read_csv, convert to categorical and save into hdf5. Once into categorical format, it nicely fits in memory.

Files are growing and I moved to Dask. Same process though.

However, in empty fields, Pandas seems to use np.nan and the category is not included in the cat.categories listing.

With Dask, empty values are filled with NaN, it is included as a separate category and whence saved into HDF I get future compatibility warning.

Is this a bug or am I missing any steps ? Behaviour seems to differ between pandas and dask.

Thanks

JC

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in dask ver 0.11.1

See https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1578